# Is Html.Encode Needed on User Credentials For Web Resource?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, security, xss

We have a simple utility which accesses a web resource for users via an HttpWebRequest.

This web resource requires login credentials (username / password). The credentials are utilized for access of the resource and are not stored in a database.

Html.Encode is used to help prevent XSS attacks. However, when these credentials are encoded, they can become broken. For instance, if a password is `john&123`, then using Html.Encode will change the password to `john&amp;123`, effectively breaking the password.

How can we safely utilize user-entered username and password strings while preventing XSS?

Or, is this not so much a problem because is XSS mainly a concern when *displaying* user input on the client browser? If so, is there anything to be aware of (security-wise) when temporarily utilizing user input to access a web resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode() or WebUtility.HtmlDecode() to get the original string back.

But, yes, you only need to worry about XSS if the string is being rendered on a page and only SQL injection if the string is used in a query that hits the database. In your case it sounds like the credentials are entered into a form by the user, used by your backend to access an external web service, and then discarded. If that's the case, XSS/SQL injection are the external web service's problem, not yours.

Comment: Agree.  Wanted to add the following link that the poster may benefit from reading: [Do you allow XSS in your passwords? You should!](http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/09/do-you-allow-xss-in-your-passwords-you.html)